# Debugging crashes on Jelly Bean

Tags: updates, 4.1-jelly-bean, crashes

I got an Allwinner-based no-name Android Tablet with 1GB RAM and a 1Ghz A8 CPU. The tablet came with Android 4.0.4, but later an upgrade for 4.1.1 was available. I upgraded my OS and while this newer version of Android feels a lot faster and responsive than 4.0.4, I got some random applications crashes which doesn't appeared on ICS.

The crashes occurs randomly and after an application dissapears from my screen there's no dialog to tell me that "Unfortunately, [application name] has stopped", making me wonder if is not the OS which kills the application. I don't know where to dig for some debugging data but while I was messing with builds.prop I found a line called `dalvik.vm.stack-trace-file` which pointed to `/data/anr/traces.txt`. I don't get any clue what is happening by reading that file, so I post it here hoping that someone will understand something from it. The most "crashy" application here is GTA 3 (most reproductible crashes), but crashes also occurs with Browser, Google Play, etc.

Do anybody have a clue about what could be the problem? Are 1GB of RAM insufficient for Jelly Bean? I post here my [build.prop](http://pastebin.com/NrY58Mxw) and [traces.txt](http://pastebin.com/xjtVCc8p) file hoping that it will be useful for solving my problem (build.props was sightly modified by me trying to get a solution for this problem). Please let me know if there's any additional information I should provide.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you do a factory reset after the upgrade? Sometimes these kinds of crashes happen if there are some remnants of the old system files left over in the upgrade which are incompatible with the new version. I'd suggest this as a first step. Note that this will clear your personal data, settings and apps, but it shouldn't touch your storage (still, use with caution).

Comment: I even reflashed the device, but the problem persist (only with 4.1.1, though).

Comment: What do you mean by 'crash'? What exactly happens?

Comment: The application just quits (disappears from screen), bringing me back to menu.

Comment: Did you wipe cache and Dalvik? Having forgotten this is the most likely source for problems like this.

Comment: I didn't tried wiping Dalvik cache, but considering that applications crashes even if I reflash the tablet I doubt that this will help. I will try it anyway and I'll let you know if it worked. Thanks